# Difference between @classmethod and a method in python

Tags: python

What is the difference between `@classmethod` and a 'classic' method in python,

When should I use the `@classmethod` and when should I use a 'classic' method in python.
Is the classmethod must be an method who is referred to the class (I mean it's only a method who handle the class) ?

And I know what is the difference between a @staticmethod and classic method
Thx

Comment: No in fact I know the difference between a staticmethod and a method, I want to know when to use a @classmethod and when to use a function in my class, and what is the difference between this methods

Comment: Then talk about *methods* and `@classmethod`.

Comment: Also see [python factory function best practices](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/166699)

Comment: Its explain what is the classmethod, not the difference between classmethod and method and when we should use @classmethod (with the cls) instead of method (with the self parameter)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume you have a class `Car` which represents the `Car` entity within your system.

A `classmethod` is a method that works for the class `Car` not on one of any of `Car`'s instances. The first parameter to a function decorated with `@classmethod`, usually called `cls`, is therefore the class itself. Example:

```
class Car(object):    
    colour = 'red'

    @classmethod
    def blue_cars(cls):
        # cls is the Car class
        # return all blue cars by looping over cls instances
```

A function acts on a particular instance of the class; the first parameter usually called `self` is the instance itself:

```
def get_colour(self):
    return self.colour
```

To sum up:

1. use `classmethod` to implement methods that work on a whole class (and not on particular class instances):

   ```
   Car.blue_cars()
   ```
2. use instance methods to implement methods that work on a particular instance:

   ```
   my_car = Car(colour='red')
   my_car.get_colour() # should return 'red'
   ```

Answer (score 7):

If you define a method inside a class, it is handled in a special way: access to it wraps it in a special object which modifies the calling arguments in order to include `self`, a reference to the referred object:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        pass

a = A()
a.f()
```

This call to `a.f` actually asks `f` (via the [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) [protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)) for an object to really return. This object is then called without arguments and deflects the call to the real `f`, adding `a` in front.

So what `a.f()` really does is calling the original `f` function with `(a)` as arguments.

In order to prevent this, we can wrap the function

1. with a `@staticmethod` decorator,
2. with a `@classmethod` decorator,
3. with one of other, similiar working, self-made decorators.

`@staticmethod` turns it into an object which, when asked, changes the argument-passing behaviour so that it matches the intentions about calling the original `f`:

```
class A(object):
    def method(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def stmethod():
        pass
    @classmethod
    def clmethod(cls):
        pass

a = A()
a.method() # the "function inside" gets told about a
A.method() # doesn't work because there is no reference to the needed object
a.clmethod() # the "function inside" gets told about a's class, A
A.clmethod() # works as well, because we only need the classgets told about a's class, A
a.stmethod() # the "function inside" gets told nothing about anything
A.stmethod() # works as well
```

So `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` have in common that they "don't care about" the concrete object they were called with; the difference is that `@staticmethod` doesn't want to know anything at all about it, while `@classmethod` wants to know its class.

So the latter gets the class object the used object is an instance of. Just replace `self` with `cls` in this case.

Now, when to use what?

Well, that is easy to handle:

- If you have an access to `self`, you clearly need an instance method.
- If you don't access `self`, but want to know about its class, use `@classmethod`. This may for example be the case with factory methods. `datetime.datetime.now()` is such an example: you can call it via its class or via an instance, but it creates a new instance with completely different data. I even used them once for automatically generating subclasses of a given class.
- If you need neither `self` nor `cls`, you use `@staticmethod`. This can as well be used for factory methods, if they don't need to care about subclassing.

Comment: A `@classmethod` takes a first argument, the class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right, I confused that.

Comment: But now your answer only talks about `staticmethod`, not `classmethod`...

Comment: @nneonneo That's what the OP originally meant; I have added a short section about `@classmethod` now.

Comment: Answers about `@staticmethod` not `@classmethod` and is __wrong__ in that the point of `@staticmethod` is that you can call `A.f()` without having to create an instance of A first.

Comment: +1 actually you've answered OP question - he mean `@staticmethod` not `@classmethod` :)

Comment: OP explains in comments that they __did__ mean `@classmethod` as in the question.

Comment: @SteveBarnes You can call it via the instance (`a.f()`) as well as via the class (`A.f()`). Both is possible.

Comment: But @glglgl the thing that makes a `@staicmethod` unique is that you can call it without an instance.  That is just about the __only__ real reason for using the decorator.

Answer (score 3):

`@classmethod` takes the class as first argument while function takes instance of the class

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def func(self):
...         print self
...     @classmethod
...     def meth(self):
...         print self

>>> t = Test()
>>> t.func()
<__main__.Test object at 0x00000000027238D0>
>>> t.meth()
<class '__main__.Test'>
```

I've used `self` argument in `meth` intentionally so it would be very close in syntax to the `func`. But usually you'd better use `cls` as argument:

```
...     @classmethod
...     def meth(cls):
...         print cls
```

Comment: Better don't name it `self`, but `cls` then.

Comment: thanks, I know that, I've used `self` just to avoid confusion and method and function declarations be as close together as possible